# Error "The App Name you entered has already been used." when adding new language

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I want to upload a new version of an iOS app to iTunes Connect. The new version of the app contains support for another language. The app name for both languages should be the same.

When I try to add the metadata for the new language in iTunes Connect, I get the following error:

```
"The App Name you entered has already been used."
```

Isn't it possible to use the same app name for different languages of the same app?

### UPDATE:

I just experienced a strange thing. When I add metadata for another language (Danish) then I can successfully use the same app name. When I want to use the same name for the English translation, I'll get the error:  "The App Name you entered has already been used."

Comment: No, you can't. If you want to support multiple languages, you should internationalize your app. Read this guide, it can help you: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html
Then, you need to summit an update of your current app.

Comment: I already localized the app. Although I want to use the same app name for every language translation. Just like Facebook for example. In every language they use the same app name.

Comment: Localize the info.plist and change the CFBundleName is the one that the app shows on the phone, it could not match the same name on appstore.

Comment: Sorry "it could not match the same name on appstore" I was meaning that it could have a different name from the appstore

Answer (score 4):

It seems possible to register an existing app name if the default languages differ.

Someone else might have registered the app name with the default language set to english.

I just asked a question about this behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765154/why-is-it-possible-to-register-an-existing-app-name-in-itunesconnect-for-each-la